# Error: FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 2, character 1)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to set up payments into Flutter via Strap, but I am having an issue when I click on the button 'checkout', which will refer to the payment page.
Once clicked, a error message shows up, that says 'Error: FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 2, character 1)'.

I think this can be related to the jsonResponse, that does not refer a JSON object?
Does anyone has an idea?
Thank you so much for your help [SEE IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtVmz.png)

```
`[tag:import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_stripe/flutter_stripe.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../models/product.dart';

class PaymentHandler {
  final String? payIntentId;
  final bool isError;
  final String message;

  PaymentHandler({
    this.payIntentId,
    required this.isError,
    required this.message,
  });
}

class PaymentService {
  PaymentService();

  Future<PaymentHandler> initPaymentSheet(User user, double totalAmount) async {
    try {
      // 1. create payment intent on the server
      final response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(
              'http://us-central1-ecommerceapp-34d7f.cloudfunctions.net/stripePaymentIntentRequest'),
          body: {
            'email': user.email,
            'amount': (totalAmount * 100).toString(),
          });

      final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);

      //2. initialize the payment sheet
      await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
        paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
          paymentIntentClientSecret: jsonResponse['paymentIntent'],
          merchantDisplayName: 'Flutter Stripe Store Demo',
          customerId: jsonResponse['customer'],
          customerEphemeralKeySecret: jsonResponse['ephemeralKey'],
          style: ThemeMode.light,
          testEnv: true,
          merchantCountryCode: 'US',
        ),
      );
      // 3. Present to the user and await the result
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
      return PaymentHandler(
          isError: false,
          message: "Success",
          payIntentId: jsonResponse['paymentIntent']);
      // Note: This is better done through our cloud functions

    } catch (e) {
      if (e is StripeException) {
        return PaymentHandler(
            isError: true,
            message: 'Error from Stripe: ${e.error.localizedMessage}');
      } else {
        return PaymentHandler(isError: true, message: 'Error: ${e}');
      }
    }
  }
}]`
```

I tried to flutter upgrade, re authenticate my firebase account, change the variables...

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a web page instead of JSON from your API call.
It can happen because one of the two reason:

1. The API needs to be authenticated. In that case you need to add authentication/authorization header on your request like:

   ```
   var headers = {  'Authorization': 'Bearer <your_token>' }
   ```
2. The API requires to define content type and or accept header like:

   ```
   var headers = {   
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Accept': 'application/json'
              }
   ```

Or combination of both:

```
             { 
               'Authorization': 'Bearer <your_token>',
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Accept': 'application/json'
              }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! :D See my code update as a 2nd comment below, but once I do that, it says Error: Failed to payse header value (I replace private_key by the private key that I had from Stripe)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Future<PaymentHandler> initPaymentSheet(User user, double totalAmount) async {
    
    try {
     // 1. create payment intent on the server
     final response = await http.post(
         Uri.parse(
             'http://us-central1-ecommerceapp-34d7f.cloudfunctions.net/stripePaymentIntentRequest'),
         body: json.encode({
           'email': user.email,
           'amount': (totalAmount * 100).toString(),
         }), 
        headers: {
          "Authorization": 'Bearer <private_key>',
          "Content-Type" : 'application/json',
          "Accept": 'application/json'}
       );
     
       final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body) ;
```